# How may I remedy this erroneous lighting pattern?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

What I did:

```
cylinderPlot3D[f_ ,xys_:1] :=   ParametricPlot3D[{z,f[t,z] Cos[t],f[t,z] 
Sin[t]}, {t,-Pi, Pi},{z,-Pi,Pi}, Mesh->None,PlotPoints->50,PlotRange -> 
All,Exclusions->None, AxesLabel->{x,y,z},Lighting -> 
{{"Directional",RGBColor[1, 1, 1], {-4,0,4}}},PlotStyle -> 
Specularity[0]]

f[t_,z_] := Cos[z/2]^0.5 * (0.9+HeavisideTheta[z-0.25 Pi]);cylinderPlot3D[f,0.6]
```

What I got, after reorientation:

[image]

showing dark at the pointer, as opposed to light as is correct, given that the ring is planar (reorient to see), the illumination is directional hence rays to all points on the ring should have the same angle of incidence hence intensity of illumination.

What I want: Correct illumination.

Comment: 1) What exactly would you consider "correct" lighting in this context? 2) Have you taken a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lighting.html ?

Comment: 1) In accord with "Directional light sources ... are taken to yield parallel simulated light rays" reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lighting.html 2) Yes :-)

Answer (score 10):

It appears to be a bug in computing the vertex normals at the step. Here's are the vertex normals:

```
c = cylinderPlot3D[f, 0.6];

normals = FirstCase[c, GraphicsComplex[pts_, __, VertexNormals -> vn_, ___] :>
 Line[Transpose@{pts, pts + vn}], -1];

Show[c, Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], normals}]]
```

[image]

It looks like the `HeavisideTheta` function is not being handled properly. A simple but imperfect workaround is to use a soft step function in its place. For example

```
step[x_] := (1 + Tanh[10 x])/2

f[t_, z_] := Cos[z/2]^0.5*(0.9 + step[z - 0.25 Pi]);

cylinderPlot3D[f, 0.6]
```

[image]

To get a more accurate result you should probably remove the `Exclusions -> None` and supply the missing part as a separate surface. I suggest reporting the problem to Wolfram if you haven't already.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89387

Comment: @Simon Thanks. The workaround suffers a lesser but still significant  discrepancy in incident intensity, and supplying the missing part would need to be computationally, give f can vary. I'll report the bug and fingers crossed.

Comment: @Simon, as an aside, is your first graphic really from the code shown? Here (on Programming Cloud) I get different: http://i.imgur.com/r59pAIm.png

Comment: @Simon. Ah, I get that only after reorientation. I guess this bug: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89472/why-does-this-graphics3d-example-change-lighting-on-reorient