# Change in Lighting and Show in V10?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

According the documentation for [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html):

> - Options explicitly specified in `Show` override those included in the graphics expression.
> - The lists of non-default options in the `Subscript[g, i]` are concatenated.

In the three plots below, the `Lighting` option(s) of the components are placed in different arguments:

- `p1` has the `Lighting` option added to `Show`.
- `p2` has the `Lighting` option in each component plot.
- `p3` has the `Lighting` option in the first component plot only.

The resulting plots are pairwise different in V10.0.0+ (up to V10.2 currently).  The plots are all the same in V9.0.1.  (Mac OS.)

```
Clear[f];
f[t_, z_] := Cos[z/2]^0.5*(1 + HeavisideTheta[z - 0.35 Pi]);
r1 = f[0, z] /. HeavisideTheta -> (0 &) /. z -> 0.35 Pi;
r2 = f[0, z] /. HeavisideTheta -> (1 &) /. z -> 0.35 Pi;

p1 = Show[ (* Lighting -> ... added in Show *)
   ParametricPlot3D[{f[t, z] Cos[t], f[t, z] Sin[t], -z},
    {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, 0.35 Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0]],
   ParametricPlot3D[{f[t, z] Cos[t], f[t, z] Sin[t], -z},
    {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, 0.35 Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0]],
   ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], -0.35 Pi},
    {t, -Pi, Pi}, {r, r1, r2}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0]],
   PlotRange -> All,
   Lighting -> {{"Directional", RGBColor[1, 1, 1], {-4, 0, 4}}}(*****)];
p2 = Show[ (* Lighting -> ... in each plot *)
   ParametricPlot3D[{f[t, z] Cos[t], f[t, z] Sin[t], -z},
    {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, 0.35 Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0],
    Lighting -> {{"Directional", RGBColor[1, 1, 1], {-4, 0, 4}}}(*****)],
   ParametricPlot3D[{f[t, z] Cos[t], f[t, z] Sin[t], -z},
    {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, 0.35 Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0],
    Lighting -> {{"Directional", RGBColor[1, 1, 1], {-4, 0, 4}}}(*****)],
   ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], -0.35 Pi},
    {t, -Pi, Pi}, {r, r1, r2}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0],
    Lighting -> {{"Directional", RGBColor[1, 1, 1], {-4, 0, 4}}}(*****)],
   PlotRange -> All];
p3 = Show[  (* Lighting -> ... in first plot only *)
   ParametricPlot3D[{f[t, z] Cos[t], f[t, z] Sin[t], -z},
    {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, 0.35 Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0], 
    Lighting -> {{"Directional", RGBColor[1, 1, 1], {-4, 0, 4}}}(*****)],
   ParametricPlot3D[{f[t, z] Cos[t], f[t, z] Sin[t], -z},
    {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, 0.35 Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0]],
   ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], -0.35 Pi},
    {t, -Pi, Pi}, {r, r1, r2}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0]],
   PlotRange -> All];
```

Here are the output of V10.0.0+ (top row) and V9.0.1 (bottom row):

```
GraphicsRow[{p1, p2, p3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this a bug or an undocumented change?

---

Discovered while investigating questions related to [How to avoid these garbage and missing mesh lines in ParametricPlot3D?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89372/how-to-avoid-these-garbage-and-missing-mesh-lines-in-parametricplot3d)

Comment: Related: [(54606)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54606/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the result of Plot Themes.  This restores the old behavior:

```
SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D, PlotTheme -> None];
```

More specifically the default Theme results in embedded `Lighting` values:

```
Cases[
 ParametricPlot3D[{f[t, z] Cos[t], f[t, z] Sin[t], -z}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, 0.35 Pi, Pi}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0], PlotTheme -> "Default"],
 HoldPattern[Lighting -> _],
 -1
]
```

> ```
> {Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[
>     0.30100577, 0.22414668499999998`, 0.090484535]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[
>     0.2642166, 0.18331229999999998`, 0.04261530000000001], 
>     ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[
>     0.2642166, 0.18331229999999998`, 0.04261530000000001], 
>     ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[
>     0.2642166, 0.18331229999999998`, 0.04261530000000001], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}}
> ```

This is not given as a standard option for `Graphics3D` but within the directives:

```
{EdgeForm[], RGBColor[0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051], 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.301006, 0.224147, 0.0904845]}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.264217, 0.183312, 0.0426153], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.264217, 0.183312, 0.0426153], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.264217, 0.183312, 0.0426153], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}, 
 AbsoluteThickness[2], Specularity[0], 
 GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[{{454, 226, 2}, {457, 232, 5}, . . .
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Since V10, I tend to think all plotting problems are due to plot themes. :)  Perhaps you have seen the [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23101100#23101100) of this issue? I am hoping rcollyer will post his view, but I guess we'll see if he feels he has anything to add.